# Spark - Optimize calculation time over a data frame, by using groupBy() instead of filter()

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame which contains different columns ('features').

My goal is to calculate column X statistical measures:
Mean, Standart-Deviation, Variance

But, to calculate all of those, with dependency on column Y.
e.g. Get all rows which Y = 1, and for them calculate mean,stddev, var,
then do the same for all rows which Y = 2 for them.

My current implementation is:

```
print "For CONGESTION_FLAG = 0:"
log_df.filter(log_df[flag_col] == 0).select([mean(size_col), stddev(size_col),
                                         pow(stddev(size_col), 2)]).show(20, False)

print "For CONGESTION_FLAG = 1:"
log_df.filter(log_df[flag_col] == 1).select([mean(size_col), stddev(size_col),
                                         pow(stddev(size_col), 2)]).show(20, False)
print "For CONGESTION_FLAG = 2:"
log_df.filter(log_df[flag_col] == 2).select([mean(size_col), stddev(size_col),
                                         pow(stddev(size_col), 2)]).show(20, False)
```

I was told the `filter()` way is wasteful in terms of computation times, and received an advice that for making those calculation run faster (i'm using this on 1GB data file), it would be better use `groupBy()` method.

Can someone please help me transform those lines to do the same calculations by using groupBy instead?
I got mixed up with the syntax and didn't manage to do so correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter by itself is not wasteful. The problem is that you are calling it multiple times (once for each value) meaning you are scanning the data 3 times. The operation you are describing is best achieved by groupby which basically aggregates data per value of the grouped column.

You could do something like this:

```
agg_df = log_df.groupBy(flag_col).agg(mean(size_col).alias("mean"), stddev(size_col).alias("stddev"), pow(stddev(size_col),2).alias("pow"))
```

You might also get better performance by calculating stddev^2 after the aggregation (you should try it on your data):

```
agg_df = log_df.groupBy(flag_col).agg(mean(size_col).alias("mean"), stddev(size_col).alias("stddev"))
agg_df2 = agg_df.withColumn("pow", agg_df["stddev"] * agg_df["stddev"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer. will using `log_df.cache()` prior to the aggregated_df creation will help improve performance?

Comment: Depends on how you generate and use log_df. If you just create it (e.g. reading from a file) then you would get no benefit. If you are reusing it for other things and have enough memory then probably yes.

Comment: I'm reading a text file (1GB) and then manipulating some columns values, removing some rows by some conditions on other columns and then go to calculations. i want to add df.cache() just before the calculations by groupBy \ aggregate methods

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
log_df.groupBy(log_df[flag_col]).agg(
    mean(size_col), stddev(size_col), pow(stddev(size_col), 2)
)
```